# Coveo Breadcrumb - How do you customize the Text?

Tags: coveo

I am using vanilla Coveo Hive components on my Sitecore website.  I have created and configured a search page.  This page uses the `Coveo Breadcrumbs` component, and everything is hooked up and working.

Whenever a facet is selected, this component renders the text `Clear`.  How do you control and customize this text?  It appears that this rendering does not have a datasource or rendering parameters, and I can't find any documentation regarding dictionary keys.

For clarification, this is the text element I am attempting to change: http://prntscr.com/oysgr3

I know I can do it within CSS, but I'd prefer to avoid hardcoding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an option for this out of the box, The Breadcrumb component displays a summary of the currently active query filters and created using Coveo's Search UI framework. In Coveo Search UI, `drawBreadcrumb` is responsible to create the breadcrumb and clear button.

https://coveo.github.io/search-ui/components/breadcrumb.html#drawbreadcrumb

If you want to control the text from the Sitecore I would suggest you, to create a custom breadcrumb control to read the clear text from Sitecore and override the `drawbreadcrumb` method for adding text on UI. Below is how in OOTB breadcrumb control manage the clear text and icon using Search UI-

```
Breadcrumb.prototype.drawBreadcrumb = function (breadcrumbs) {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    var clearIcon = Dom_1.$$('div', {
        className: 'coveo-icon coveo-breadcrumb-clear-all-icon'
    }, SVGIcons_1.SVGIcons.icons.checkboxHookExclusionMore).el;
    SVGDom_1.SVGDom.addClassToSVGInContainer(clearIcon, 'coveo-breadcrumb-clear-all-svg');
    clear.appendChild(clearIcon);
    //Manage the Clear Text
    var clearText = Dom_1.$$('div', undefined, Strings_1.l('Clear', '')).el;
    clear.appendChild(clearText);
    this.element.appendChild(clear);
};
```